How to replace (or add) the bottom seal of my tilt-up garage door?
I am wondering if anyone can help me with figuring out if my garage door is able to replace or add a bottom seal? Photos are linked here.
I bought a generic garage bottom seal on amazon thinking that all garage doors were universal with the bottom seal, but once I opened my garage and actually looked at the bottom I realized my garage door doesn't have the tracks that allow a seal to slide through it.
My garage door is a tilt-up style garage door. I tried searching google but have not been able to find an answer. Do doors like these even use bottom seals? The bottom of my garage door is a flat piece of metal and attached to the rest of the garage door in multiple different areas.
There is a strip of rubber that sticks out of the bottom of the garage door which initially led me to think that this can be replaced, but I am starting to think this may not be possible. Any information anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much in advance.

What is your aim in adding a seal to the bottom of the door—keep debris out?  keep critters out?  keep water out?

I believe on that style of door, you have a "sweep" for the bottom edge. On the first pic, that's the exterior piece on the bottom edge that looks like a flap and on yours is broken in places. I would be looking for something like this:
Cleverseal Tilt Garage Door Seals
